# Jssor captions not animating

Tags: animation, slider, jssor, captions

Jssor i great! - But when i included the banner in my code through my DNN7 CMS, the captions doesn't animate, even though the slides change as expected - i wrote:

```
    <div class="container" style="padding:0px !important">
    <div id="slider1_container" style="display: none; position: relative; margin: 0 0; width: 1100px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1100px; height: 300px;" u="slides">
    <div><img src="/portals/0/designelementer/headlines/agHeader6.jpg" u="image" />
<div style="position:absolute;" t="ZM" u="caption">Bliv medlem</div>
</div>
<div><img src="/portals/0/designelementer/headlines/agHeader1.jpg" u="image" /></div></div></div></div>
```

You can see the page here: [Link](http://www.arbejdsgiverne.dk/dev/jesper-a/revolution-slider)

(**Beware**, it's in danish)

Anybody got a hint for me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post jssor slider initialization code.

Comment: [You can find initialization code here](http://www.arbejdsgiverne.dk/jquery/jssor.config.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move `$CaptionSliderOptions` out from `$BulletNavigatorOptions`.

replace

```
    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 12,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
        $Scale: false,                                   //Scales bullets navigator or not while slider scale
        $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
            $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
            $PlayInMode: 1,
            $PlayOutMode: 3
        }
    }
```

with

```
    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 12,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
        $Scale: false                                   //Scales bullets navigator or not while slider scale
    },
    $CaptionSliderOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
        $PlayInMode: 1,
        $PlayOutMode: 3
    }
```

Comment: Doesnt help me unfortunately :-( Slider plays allright, but Caption only "fades" in.